# Use ADASYN for multi class-multilable models

Tags: imbalanced-data

I have a multiclass-multilabel model, how to use the ADASYN to do data augmentation so that data is balanced,
An example to understand my question:
Dataset has 10 features,
Classes for dataset I have : Green and Orange, each label within each class: round or square; So an object can be in above 4 status(green round, green square, orange round orange square), green-round=4, green-square=20, orange-round=15, orange-square = 60
How should I use ADASYN for this multi class-multi label model so that after ADASYN I can get green-round=60,green-square=60,orange-round=60, orange-square=60 ?